# GSON Not an Object Error

Tags: javascript, json, gson

I have the following json object:

```
cNGJSON = {
            "one": graph1.graphNode, "two": graph2.graphNode, "three": graph3.graphNode, "four": graph4.graphNode, "five": graph5.graphNode,"six": graph6.graphNode,
            "seven": graph7.graphNode,"eight": graph8.graphNode, "nine": graph9.graphNode,"ten": graph10.graphNode, "eleven": graph11.graphNode, "twelve": graph12.graphNode,
            "thirteen": graph13.graphNode,"fourteen": graph14.graphNode,"fifteen": graph15.graphNode,"sixteen": graph16.graphNode, "seventeen": graph17.graphNode, "eighteen": graph18.graphNode,
            "nineteen": graph19.graphNode   
    };
```

where graph1.graphNode is an integer array.

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

I send this to the server with jQuery:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: 'validate',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success!!");
            },
            data: cNGJSON
        });
```

However I get a

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
```

Error every time I try.

I tried with setting the cNGJSON to:

```
cNGJSON = { 
            "one": "Number one", "two": "Number two"
    };
```

Still I get the same error.

Comment: I think that you're supposed to use `jsonData: cNGJSON`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you want to send JSON object in your XHR request you need to stringify the JSON object first

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'validate',
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {
         console.log("Success!!");
     },
     data: JSON.stringify(cNGJSON)
});
```